# symfony 1.4, accessing module level lib in a custom task

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have 2 applications: frontend and backend.

I am running the custom task with the following command:

```
php symfony newCron:createClusters --application=frontend
```

In each applications I have a `lib` folder and a `modules` folder. Through the above command only this `apps->frontend->lib` folder is accessible, whereas the lib folder in `apps->frontend->modules->module1->lib` is not accessible.

How can I access the module level lib files in my task?

I tried using the addOption command in the config method, but still nothing happens.

Comment: But lib from the `module->lib` folder aren't autoloaded ?

Comment: Why don't you move these libs in the `/lib` or `frontend/lib` folder instead since there aren't dedicated to the module (as you want to access them from the task) ?

Comment: actually i hav module specific tasks that I need to run from the command line. And I think the tasks can be made either in lib/task or plugins/lib/task folders only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two options.

**The "symfony way"**

Using `autoload.yml` (in `apps/frontend/config/autoload.yml`):

```
autoload:
  my_module_lib:
    path:        %SF_APP_MODULE_DIR%/name_of_your_module/lib
    recursive:   true
```

**The "php old way"**

Using basic `require_once` inside your task:

```
class createClustersTask extends sfBaseTask
{
  /**
   * @see sfTask
   */
  protected function configure()
  {
    require_once sfConfig::get('sf_app_module_dir') . '/name_of_your_module/lib/name_of_your_first_lib.class.php';
    require_once sfConfig::get('sf_app_module_dir') . '/name_of_your_module/lib/name_of_your_second_lib.class.php';
```

Comment: how do i call the module library part of autoload.yml from my task?

Comment: Since your are giving the application for the task, it will be automatically loaded.